# Load database into PostgreSQL from text file

Tags: database, postgresql

ALL,

I have a text file which contains multiple SQL statements, like:

```
CREATE TABLE a();
CREATE TABLE b();
INSERT INTO a() VALUES();
INSERT INTO b() VALUES();
```

This file is generated from the SQLite database.

What I'd like to do is to load this file into PostgreSQL database. I already created the database on the server and now I want to populate the database structure and the data.

The whole DB structure contain in 1 file.

Is it possible to just load this file into the PostgreSQL? Or I will have to split the file and then manually create all tables and issue "LOAD" command?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your file look like? It sounds like you are trying to split the contents out into multiple tables, is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Nicarus, I gave an example in my post. It just a set of SQL command from the SQLite .schema command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PG_RESTORE will not work unless the source file is from a PG_DUMP.

Your best bet is to fire this off as an .SQL file on connection to the database.
eg.

```
psql -d [database] -U [user] -f [file from SQLite].sql
```

As long as the commands in the file are executable and the syntax will work with Postgres this will create your objects and populate them.